# How to write a string in a date column in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In a GridView, the column `LastLogin` is nullable DateTime.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="LastLogin" 
     ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LastLogin" />
```

I want to show in the cell the label `"Just Created"` if the value of `LastLogin` is null.

How can I do that ?

Can I use Format of the field ?

I've tried to do that in the `RowDataBound` event handler but I could not access to the appropriate cell by the column name, it's only possible by the index of the column and I don't prefer that.

Any idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using the NullDisplayText property on BoundField...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.nulldisplaytext.aspx

Comment: Great, thanks :) I was trying with something more complicated.